# Composite foreign keys in Rails ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

I currently have a model named `Image`. This model is tied to an `Article`.

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many: images
end
```

The Image table contains an `article_id`, so an image is associated with an article.

However, I would like to use my images together with other models as well. Therefore I imagine changing `article_id` into something like `owner_id` and add a new attribute called `owner_model` to the `Image` model.

That way other models can also have many images.

Any idea if this is possible to achieve gracefully using ActiveRecord and how to go about it?

On a sidenote, I am using CarrierWave for images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use polymorphic associations.

The [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) has a neat example that goes with your question.

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :imageable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures, :as => :imageable
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures, :as => :imageable
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into polymorphic associations?  Ryan has a video up on it: http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association

It will allow you to associate different classes with your images.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called polymorphic associations ( http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations ).